# Using the FB "Like" generator i can't get it to work on my web page

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

I am not a web designer so please bear with me but I have followed the FB like generator and copied the iframes element to my web site but it does not appear when published. Can anybody tell me what I am missing...??? the code generated is:-

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fweebagband&amp;width=The+pixel+width+of+the+plugin&amp;height=80&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;send=false&amp;appId=271163222908481" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:The pixel width of the pluginpx; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

From this I have been even tried to paste it to a blank page but still nothing. 
Even the simple Google FB "like" generator didn't work. I'd be most grateful for any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com/weebagband&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80&amp;appId=271163222908481" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Your code has some errors, like `width:The pixel width of the pluginpx;`

And I think the url to your FB Page was wrong as well..

I assume that [weebagband](https://www.facebook.com/weebagband) is the desired fanpage..